# image classification own data

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have my own dataset folder which has 40 images, I want to perform image classification on my data. I don't understand how to upload datasets images into jupyter and how to perform image classification.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour
page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to
ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you tried any code? Did it error out or not work at all? You might want to start with a tutorial on youtube on basics of ML.

Comment: I would suggest you go through [this tutorial](https://blog.azhanmohammed.xyz/training-a-classifier-using-py-torch), should be really helpful.

Comment: This tutorial could also be helpful https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/create-image-classification-model-python-keras/

Answer (score -1):

Let's say name of your data directory is *train*
create a *new folder* inside **train** directory let's name it **dog**

```
 Datadirectory = 'train/'
    Classes = ['dog']
    for category in Classes:
        path = os.path.join(Datadirectory,category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
            plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img_array,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            plt.show()
            break
        break
```

This will work